# socket php, php, slow socket, better perform socket

Tags: php, performance, sockets

I create an aplicattion for read value from a PLC. 
When I used one function socket the php page works fine, but when i put two or more I need around 20secundes to open one php.

Somene Knwos i can improve my code or sockets in php are like this???

The his my code:

```
<?php
    $dados_recebidos = analisa_dados_dos_turnos($host, $port);
    $ranking = prioridade_dos_turnos($host, $port);
?>
<?php
    function  analisa_dados_dos_turnos($host, $port)
    {   
        $message = "01ff000a4420000002583f00"; // D600 a D662
        $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Could not create socket\n");     
        $result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");        
        socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");        
        $result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");       
        socket_shutdown($socket);   
        return $result;
    }
    function prioridade_dos_turnos($host, $port)
    {   
        $message = "01ff000a4420000004291000"; // D1065 a D1079
        $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Could not create socket\n");     
        $result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");        
        socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");        
        $result = socket_read ($socket, 2048) or die("Could not read server response\n");       
        //socket_shutdown($socket); 
        return $result;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why are you not using socket_shutdown() on the $ranking socket?

Comment: Normally I use socket_close(), but its the same for me.
The point is. . .i need 20 seconds to upload the page, and i dont know why :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it the same if you repeat analisa_dados_dos_turnos() multiple times?

I'm not a socket expert but I would try adding some time counting code to see which piece is causing the delay.

```
    $start_time = microtime(TRUE);
     //DO SOMETHING
    $stop_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $elapsedtime = $stop_time - $start_time;
    echo '<BR>Elapsed Time: '.$elapsedtime;
```

For example You could

```
    $start_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $dados_recebidos = analisa_dados_dos_turnos($host, $port);
    $stop_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $elapsedtime = $stop_time - $start_time;
    echo '<BR>dados_recebidos 1 Elapsed Time: '.$elapsedtime;

    $start_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $dados_recebidos = analisa_dados_dos_turnos($host, $port);
    $stop_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $elapsedtime = $stop_time - $start_time;
    echo '<BR>dados_recebidos 2 Elapsed Time: '.$elapsedtime;

    $start_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $ranking = prioridade_dos_turnos($host, $port);
    $stop_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $elapsedtime = $stop_time - $start_time;
    echo '<BR>ranking 1 Elapsed Time: '.$elapsedtime;

    $start_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $ranking = prioridade_dos_turnos($host, $port);
    $stop_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $elapsedtime = $stop_time - $start_time;
    echo '<BR>ranking 2 Elapsed Time: '.$elapsedtime;
```

and to break it down even farther try this

```
     function prioridade_dos_turnos($host, $port)
{   
    $message = "01ff000a4420000004291000"; // D1065 a D1079

    $start_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die("Could not create socket\n"); 
    $stop_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $elapsedtime = $stop_time - $start_time;
    echo '<BR>socket_create Elapsed Time: '.$elapsedtime;

    $start_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");
    $stop_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $elapsedtime = $stop_time - $start_time;
    echo '<BR>socket_connect Elapsed Time: '.$elapsedtime;

    $start_time = microtime(TRUE);
    socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
    $stop_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $elapsedtime = $stop_time - $start_time;
    echo '<BR>socket_write Elapsed Time: '.$elapsedtime;

    $start_time = microtime(TRUE);        
    $result = socket_read ($socket, 2048) or die("Could not read server response\n");
    $stop_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $elapsedtime = $stop_time - $start_time;
    echo '<BR>socket_read Elapsed Time: '.$elapsedtime; 

    $start_time = microtime(TRUE);       
    socket_shutdown($socket);
    $stop_time = microtime(TRUE);
    $elapsedtime = $stop_time - $start_time;
    echo '<BR>socket_shutdown Elapsed Time: '.$elapsedtime;         
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Greg I already measuring the time, and i have 3 seconds for all code on php page. 

I have two pages one constantly receive, other constantly send. . .Has possible the problem is socket crashing doing two tasks at the same time?